# Can I set user agent for embedded web view in both iOS and android apps for Google Login?

Tags: android, ios, google-signin

I have an app on both iOS and android platforms where I am using WKWebView for login using a Google account. I get this error message *Authorization Error 403: disallowed_useragent*. As mentioned in other older posts, can I set custom user agent for web view as a workaround. Is it still a viable solution considering Google will not allow web view to use Google Sign In.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is information here about what to do on Android and iOS instead of using embedded webviews: https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html#instructions

On Android, you can use Android Custom Tabs and on iOS, you can use SFSafariViewController.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS I found using the WebView class much easier than the SFSafariViewController.

In Obj-C this also works.
I got ours to work like this:

```
-(void)loadWebViewPage
{
    
        WKWebViewConfiguration *configureWebView = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        configureWebView.applicationNameForUserAgent = @"Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5";//set minimum version of safari to get rid of incompatible message
        WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configureWebView];
        webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    
        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"the login url"];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
    
}
```